# Recursive binary search

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, binary-search

In my main file I have an array of character strings, char names[320][30], and after I sort that with a bubble sort. I want to be able to do a recursive binary search to determine if a word is present in the names array and what its index is.  The index is represented by a set of unsigned ints, unsigned int Set[10].  If the word is not present, the function should return -1.

```
#include "set.h"
#include "sortAndSearch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int binarySearch(Char A[][30], char *, int, int){
//this gets passed the global array names
//and the spot we're looking for is the char pointer
//other 2 ints are low = 0, and high = 319
//then it finds mid, a point between high and low
//and then does the same thing on whichever half it needs
//until it finds the index its looking for
//this is recursive because of the low and high values provided

int mid, low, high, result;

//calculate midpoint to cut set in half
mid = (high + low)/2;

//comparison
result = strcmp(A[mid], key);

//if result < 0, A[mid] < key
if(result < 0)
        return binarySearch(A, key, mid+1, high);

//if result > 0, A[mid] > key
else if(result > 0)
        return binarySearch(A, key, low, mid-1);

//if result == 0, A[mid] == key
else if(result == 0)
        return mid;

//couldnt find it
else
        return -1;

//this should return int, either
//the index where the string being searched for is stored in the array
//or -1 to indicate that the string beinng sought is not in the array
}
```

And in my main function, I call the function:

```
char *key;
binarySearch(names, key, 0, 319);
```

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:

- search.c:7: parse error before "A"
- search.c: In function `binarySearch':
- search.c:7: number of arguments doesn't match prototype
- sortAndSearch.h:3: prototype declaration
- search.c:22: `A' undeclared (first use in this function)
- search.c:22: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
- search.c:22: for each function it appears in.)
- search.c:22: `key' undeclared (first use in this function)

So my question is why am I getting these errors, as I do not see any typos, and what's up with the number of arguments not matching prototype?  I copied it right from the sortAndSearch.h file I was given.

Comment: Try changing `Char` to `char` at the definition of `binarySearch` and then see if your code compiles.

Comment: BTW---the general rule is to always worry about *only* the first compiler error because errors may cascade. (There are some compiler that do a decent job of recovering and provide subsequent meaningful errors, but not every compiler falls into that set and you won't go wrong by handling only the first one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int binarySearch(Char A[][30], char *, int, int){
```

That `Char` should probably be `char` (C is a case-sensitive language).  Because this was wrong, most of the other compilation errors are consequences of the compiler being confused.

You also need to give names to the other arguments in a function definition:

```
int binarySearch(Char A[][30], char *key, int low, int high){
```

You then don't need `low` and `high` as separately declared local variables (indeed, you aren't allowed to declare them as local variables as well as parameters).

There is also a bug in the logic in the function, I believe:

```
if (result < 0)
        return binarySearch(A, key, mid+1, high);
else if (result > 0)
        return binarySearch(A, key, low, mid-1);
else if (result == 0)
        return mid;
else
        return -1;
```

All values are either greater than, less than, or equal to zero; the `else` clause is redundant.

However, you also have a problem with terminating your search.  You need to check whether `low` is greater than `high` before computing `mid`, and you should then return the `-1` for not found if the range to be searched is empty.

Comment: The range to be searched will always be 0-319 for the 320 bit positions I have.  The search is for the program to find a string in the array.  So if the string isn't there, I need to return -1.  Should I just drop the else and put return -1?

Comment: The first three tests cover all the bases; you can drop the else but it makes no difference.  You probably need `if (low > high) return -1;` before you calculate `mid`.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I put.  Thanks for the confirmation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is `Char A[][30]`, it should be `char A[][30]`

There's no datatype by name `Char` in standard C

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `Char` to `char` at the definition of `binarySearch` and then see if your code compiles.

Always check the first compile error. This error can lead to lots of other seemingly random errors, which appears to be what are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is C? `int binarySearch(Char A[][30], char *, int, int)` is not a valid function definition `int binarySearch(char A[][30], char *s, int a, int b)` is. Try that.

The form without names might appear in a header file. A header file has enough information for the compiler to check the data type of each argument (AKA parameter), but it doesn't need (when it reads the header) any more information. At that point the compiler is able to check any code using (calling) the function is correct. That is called the functions signature.

When the compiler sees the actual function definition, it needs the names of the arguments (AKA parameters) so that the code can refer to them, the arguments are variables. So it then needs names.

Comment: It is C, and I initially had `int binarySearch(char A[][30], char *key, int high, int low)` but in the header file it is exactly how I have it posted originally.  I thought it had to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-read the basics of C.  It's a case-sensitive language, and `Char` is not `char`.

Comment: That was given to me by my professor in a class where I'm learning the basics of C.  Thanks for asserting your superiority on the help forum.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the prof gave you, by simply referencing the line in question that the compiler threw an error on, you should be able to catch something like this.

Answer (score 0):

At line 5, the function definition needs to match with the declaration. Check sortAndSearch.h for the previous declaration of the function.
It should like

```
int binarySearch(char A[][30], char *key, int low, int high){
```

At line 14, low and high should not be declared, and it is supposed to passed as an argument to the function. It should like

```
int mid, result;
```

Otherwise it looks good.